# Customize Actionsheet

Tags: ios, swift3, uiactionsheet

[image: actionsheet like thgis]I am woking on the app which needs to show action sheet like this anyone can help??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

UIActionsheet is not customised.You are doing following library. it is the help.

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController allows us to create any custom action sheet giving much more flexibility than the solutions proposed above.

These are some examples included in the GitHub repository.